# Kinect for Windows SDK vs. SimpleOpenNI RGB image quality

Tags: windows, kinect, processing, kinect-sdk, simple-openni

I'm comapring these Kinect libraries on windows:

a) Kinect for Windows SDK for Processing (http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/2012/09/05/kinect-for-processing-library-page/)

b) SimpleOpenNI (http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/)

[image]

Link to full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmgYW.jpg

Does anyone noticed the difference in RGB image coming out of these wrappers? 
SimpleOpenNI is more pixelated and has more noises. Is it possible to get better image in SimpleOpenNI?

Thanks for any tips!